# Broadcast Receiver set for whole application

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcast

I have 2 activities - Main activity and the second activity 
Main activity switches to second activity on click of a button.

I have implemented a broadcast receiver for Bluetooth in the main activity, it only works on main activity. How do I declare receiver for the whole application , also I must be able to unregister on onPause method for the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Are you implemented it using register the receiver using manifest file? If yes, it will be applicable for the entire system.That is code inside the on receive() will be trigger even if your application is not up.This feature is use full to start an application from the android system startup.Otherwise , you can implement Broadcast Receiver by registering it in the code itself .Then register the receiver in on create() or in resume() & unregister it in onPause() methods of activities. In your case , do it in your both activities.

Answer (score 0):

For this, You have to register the broadcast receiver in each activity and onPause(), unregister it.

For example, you can follow this link :
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/03/android-broadcast-receiver-in-detail.html#.VC-TuRanHIU

but you to get in the whole application , you have to do it in the each activity